# C# REST API Client

Tags: c#, wpf, api, rest

I have successfully created a PHP REST API which resides on my server. I am now looking to create the client-side connection to this via my WPF C# application. I found [this](http://www.nikhilk.net/CSharp-Dynamic-Programming-REST-Services.aspx) but my API requires the API key to be sent via a HTTP header, and I can't see you can do that in this. I also created a PHP REST client using CURL and it was very easy, and was hoping that there would be something built into C# to handle requests to REST services.

If someone could point me in the direction of a tutorial they have seen, or a library somewhere I would be grateful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Take a look at [RESTSharp](http://restsharp.org/). Very powerful, and easy to use.

Works on all platforms too: Web, Windows, WCF, Monotouch, Windows Phone

Comment: Perfect, just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 13):

You can just use [HttpWebRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx) or [WebClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx) to make web requests like you would have with CURL in your PHP client...

If you need to deal with JSON based responses, JSON.Net is a fantastic library.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://a/rest/uri");
request.Method = "POST";
request.Headers.Add("Authorization: OAuth " + accessToken);
string postData = string.Format("param1=something&param2=something_else");
byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.Accept = "application/json";
request.ContentLength = data.Length;

using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    requestStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}

try
{
    using(WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
    {
        // Do something with response
    }
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    // Handle error
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Also you can use [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx) in .NET 4.5.
If you are usint .NET 4.0, the `HttpClient` API is available in [Microsoft.Net.Http](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http) nuget.

Comment: This is the answer according to new DotNet 4.5 libraries.

Answer (score 5):

You might also want to check out Hammock.NET @ http://hammock.codeplex.com/ ; it is a joy to work with. You really don't need WCF in all likelyhood.

Answer (score 1):

If your PHP REST API backend is documented with Swagger, e.g. using [swagger-php](https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php), you can use [swagger-codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen) to generate the API clients in C#, Java, PHP, Ruby, Python and more using the Swagger spec that describes your PHP backend.