# Calling a c# methode from javascript/jquery and get the result

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a dialog in an ASP.Net,c# application.This dialog has a textbox.When I choose save I want to call a function from C# who makes some verifications in the database and then to get the result in javascript/jquery.If the inserted value is true I want to close the dialog other way to remain opened,but I can't succed to close the dialog box after i receive true from c# function.Below is the code:

ascx :

```
    <div id="popup" title="Choose Delegate">
        <label>Delegate<label><input type="textbox" value="" name="inputD" id=="inputD"/>
     </div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#btnAdd').click(function(e){
$('#divPopup').slow("show");
$('#divPopup').dialog({
      height:150,
      width:300,
      modal:true,
      buttons:{
               "close":function(){$(this).dialog("close");}
               "save":function(){
                  var obj=document.getElementid("inputD");

                  $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "add.aspx/check",
                    data: "{delegate: '" + obj.Value+"'}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (msg) {
                          rez= "OK";
                          $(this).dialog("close");
                         },
                    failure: function () {alert("FAIL"); }});                    }
        });
      }
```

C#:

```
[WebMethode]
public static Boolean check(string delegate)
{
   .....

   return true;

  }
```

C# methode returns corect value.

I try also this :

```
       $('#btnAdd').click(function(e){

           $('#divPopup').slow("show");
           $('#divPopup').dialog({
                       height:150,
                       width:300,
                       modal:true,
                       buttons:{
             "close":function(){$(this).dialog("close");}

            "save":function(){
                  var obj=document.getElementid("inputD");
                  var rez ;

                  $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "add.aspx/check",
                    data: "{delegate: '" + obj.Value+"'}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (msg) {
                          rez= "OK";
                                                       },
                    failure: function () {alert("FAIL"); }
                 });       

                    if (rez="OK")
                          $(this).dialog("close");

         }
        });
```

But it doesn't see the rez value in this case.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You can use an Ajax Call in your "save":function(e) and just check the returned value if true close dialog, else remain opened

Ajax calls are really simple to implement, I let you search that :)

Comment: I solved ,i must declare a variable before ajax code var dlg=$(this) ;   and then on success i mus write dlg.dialog("close");

Answer (score 0):

You need a web-service on the server side. (preferably REST)

http://restsharp.org/ is an easy to use library for that.

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970499/c-sharp-rest-api-client) for more info.

In the front end you make an ajax call to you're REST api (I see you use jquery so it won't be that hard ;))