# Calling php webservice in visual studio 2010 is giving me error releated to content type

Tags: c#, php, visual-studio-2010, web-services

I have created one webservice call in php, it is a RESET webservice.
Now I want to call this webservice in excel 2007. So I am using Visual stdio 2010.
When I give the url in add service refrence dialog box and press go. it's give me this error.

-------error------------------------------------

There was an error downloading 'http://careernet.localhost/rep-details/report_details/retrieves'.
The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not found: Could not find the controller..
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://careernet.localhost/rep-details/report_details/retrieves'.
The remote server returned an unexpected response: (406) Not Acceptable: Unsupported request content type application/soap+xml.
The remote server returned an error: (406) Not Acceptable.
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.

---

I would like to tell that url is correct. my webservice call is returning data in xml format.
I tried to convert this into json but it is not working at all.

Answer (score 0):

Service References don't work against REST webservices, they work against SOAP services or other services that provide a WSDL that describes the protocol in a way that Visual Studio understands.

You'll need to write your own proxy for it using the [Web API/HttpClient](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-clients), or you can make use of existing libraries to communicate:

- RestSharp: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4970558/736079

Comment: The link you provided is not that helpfull to me. can you give some more idea or links because i am new to c#. is there any other code snippets which explains the process properly.

Comment: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-clients/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client